# python3 subclass is being instantiated as superclass, subclass method not found throwing AttributeError

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, init, super, attributeerror

I am attempting to define and instantiate a subclass in python3, but when calling a method on the subclass it throws an AttributeError, much as if I instantiated the object as an instance of the superclass; the method cannot be found. As far as I can tell, I have written the subclass constructor appropriately, calling the super() method without arguments as shown. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code used to instantiate subclass and call method:

```
class Player:

    hands = []
    ...

    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def __deal(self, twocards):
        self.hands = [Hand(showfirst=True)]
        self.hands[0] += twocards
        self.hands[0].showcards()
    ...
```

Definition of Hand class:

```
class Hand(pydealer.Stack):

    def __init__(self, showfirst, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        stay = False
        self.showfirstcard = showfirst

    ...

    def showcards(self):
        for i, card in enumerate(self):
            if i == 0:
                if self.showfirstcard == False:
                    print('***FACEDOWN CARD***')
                else:
                    print(card)
```

Stacktrace and error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/python/django_webapp/mysite/webapp/blockjack/src/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    table.start()
  File "/root/python/django_webapp/mysite/webapp/blockjack/src/table.py", line 23, in start
    self.dealer.deal(self.shoe.deal(2))
  File "/root/python/django_webapp/mysite/webapp/blockjack/src/dealer.py", line 15, in deal
    self.seecards(0)
  File "/root/python/django_webapp/mysite/webapp/blockjack/src/player.py", line 39, in seecards
    self.hands[whichhand].showcards()
AttributeError: 'Stack' object has no attribute 'showcards'
```

TL;DR: Why does it think I am trying to call a method on a parent class object (Stack) when I explicitly defined the object in question using Hand()?

EDIT: Added all relevant code undigested below:

test.py

```
import table
from pydealer import Deck

table = table.Table()
table.start()
```

table.py

```
from pydealer import Deck
from player import Player
from dealer import Dealer

class Table:

    shoe = None
    dealer = None
    player = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.shoe = Deck()
        self.shoe.rebuild = True
        self.shoe.shuffle()
        self.player = Player()
        self.dealer = Dealer()

    def start(self):
        self.player.bet()
        self.dealer.deal(self.shoe.deal(2))
        self.player.deal(self.shoe.deal(2))
```

dealer.py

```
from player import Player
from hand import Hand

class Dealer(Player):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def deal(self, twocards):
        self.hands = [Hand(showfirst=False)]
        self.hands[0] += twocards
        self.seecards(0)
```

player.py

```
from hand.py import Hand

class Player:

    hands = []
    __chips = None
    __betamount = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.__chips = 5000

    def bet(self):
        type(self.__betamount)

    def __deal(self, twocards):
        self.hands = [Hand(showfirst=True)]
        self.hands[0] += twocards
        self.hands[0].showcards()

    def hit(self, card, whichhand):
        self.hands[whichhand] += card

    def stay(self, whichhand):
        self.hands[whichhand].setstay()

    def printscore(self, whichhand):
        print(self.hands[whichhand].stackscore())
```

hand.py

```
import pydealer

class Hand(pydealer.Stack):

    stay = None
    showfirstcard = None
    bust = None

    def __init__(self, showfirst, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        stay = False
        self.showfirstcard = showfirst

    def stackscore(self):
        total = 0
        for card in self:
            total += self.__bjval(card)
        if total > 21:
            for card in self:
                if card.value == "Ace":
                    total -= 10
                if total <= 21:
                    break
        return total

    def __bjval(self, card):
        return {
                '2': 2,
                '3': 3,
                '4': 4,
                '5': 5,
                '6': 6,
                '7': 7,
                '8': 8,
                '9': 9,
                '10': 10,
                'Jack': 10,
                'Queen': 10,
                'King': 10,
                'Ace':11
                }[card.value]

    #def receive(self, cards):
        #self += cards

    def setstay(self):
        self.stay = True

    def getsize(self):
        return self.size()

    def showcards(self):
        for i, card in enumerate(self):
            if i == 0:
                if self.showfirstcard == False:
                    print('***FACEDOWN CARD***')
                else:
                    print(card)
```

Comment: It's hard to tell because your example is incomplete. The traceback shows that it starts in the `table.start()`, but you say nothing about it. This way it's not possible to see what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The object was not being instantiated as a Stack but was actually being converted to a stack upon the result of the += operator. The code for this operator instantiates and returns new stack object and the reference to the Hand object is lost altogether. Within stack.py:

```
def __add__(self, other):

    try:
        new_stack = Stack(cards=(list(self.cards) + list(other.cards)))
    except:
        new_stack = Stack(cards=(list(self.cards) + other))

    return new_stack
```

I guess the only other way to go about this is to make the Hand class contain a Stack, since overriding the basic functionality of the superclass in this way seems to defeat the purpose of inheritance altogether?